# Animate heading change in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, uianimation

Simple question - I am trying to animate the change in heading for my map view, but haven't yet found a way to do this. I have tried using UIAnimation, but as I anticipated, this didn't work.

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func rotateToDefault(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.mapView.camera.heading = 0
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new MKMapCamera with the new heading and then animate to the new camera using `setCamera: animated:`